# Java - color gradient detection in image

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a `BufferedImage` and I need to detect whether this image contains color gradients.

There is a lot of algorithms of detecting edges, but none I found so far to detect gradients. For me it is sufficient to detect whether there is any color gradient larger than 20x20 pixels in an image.

If you could point me to some Java implementations of such detection it would be sufficient.

Comment: Need more information. What do you consider a gradient? If the slope's too shallow it approaches a 'solid' color. If the slope is too steep it's an edge. If the slope is not simple, it may be a point, split, or saddle point. Where are the thresholds of what you call a gradient? Is a split point also a gradient?

Comment: it would be ideal if I can configure the slope by a parameter. I am looking for an existing solution which takes BufferedImage - some standard implementation and I can tweak it for my needs then.

Comment: Still not enough information. Depending on if any of [these](https://imgur.com/a/k1pjJus) are considered a gradient (or none of them) different algorithms would be appropriate. At any rate, I don't know of any existing implementations besides OpenCV, with which I have little experience.

Comment: from the example you provided - I consider only 3rd one contains gradient for my use case.